# Firestore futures

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, stream

This is my next step in learning flutter and Firebase. (I have migrated all my code to Dart 2). I am getting data from a Firestore collection with this code:

```
List<Event> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) {
    // kEvents is a linkedHashMap
    for (int i = 0; i < eventDoc.length; i++ ) {
      DateTime eventDate = eventDoc[i].eventDate;
      DateTime eventDateUTC = eventDate.toUtc();
      if (day.year == eventDate.year && day.day == eventDate.day && day.month == eventDate.month) {
        List<Event> eventList = [];
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].agencyId);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].agentId);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventDate);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventDescription);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventDuration);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventName);
        eventList.add(eventDoc[i].eventStartTime);
        //print('kEvents: $kEvents');
        return (kEvents.putIfAbsent(eventDateUTC, () => eventList))??[];

      }
    }
    return [];
  }
```

I am getting a runtime error on eventDoc as follows:

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building _BodyBuilder:
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
```

I have declared eventDoc like this:

```
var eventDoc;
```

eventDoc is populated in this code:

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream: _db.collection('agency').doc(globals.agencyId).collection('event')
              .where('eventDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: kFirstDay)
              .where('eventDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: kLastDay)
                    .snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
              .map((document) => Event.fromFirestore(document.data()))
              .toList()),
            builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot <List<Event>> eventsSnapShot) {
              if (eventsSnapShot.hasData) {
                eventDoc = eventsSnapShot.data; <<<<< eventDoc populated
                return _buildTableCalendar();
              } else {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              }
            },
          ),
```

I am calling _getEventsForDay() in the eventLoader: property here:

```
Widget _buildTableCalendar() {
return TableCalendar(
      firstDay: kFirstDay,
      lastDay: kLastDay,
      focusedDay: _focusedDay,
      selectedDayPredicate: (day) => isSameDay(_selectedDay, day),
      locale: 'en_US',
      eventLoader: (day) {
        return _getEventsForDay(day);
      },
```

I'm sure I am declaring eventDoc incorrectly but I don't know how it should be declared. Please help.

Comment: where are you calling `_getEventsForDay()`?

Comment: I added the code where I call _getEventsForDay(). It is in the _buildTableCalendar function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you are trying to iterate a list that is null.

> The getter 'length' was called on null.

You can solve this error by two options:

**Option 1**

You are giving the snapshot data to your eventDoc var, but you need to update the state to notify that variable has changed

```
setState(() => eventDoc = eventsSnapShot.data );
```

**Option 2**

Other solution is pass the data to your methods

```
StreamBuilder(
        stream: _db.collection('agency').doc(globals.agencyId).collection('event')
          .where('eventDate', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: kFirstDay)
          .where('eventDate', isLessThanOrEqualTo: kLastDay)
                .snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
          .map((document) => Event.fromFirestore(document.data()))
          .toList()),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot <List<Event>> eventsSnapShot) {
          if (eventsSnapShot.hasData) {
            if ( eventsSnapShot.data != null ) {
              return _buildTableCalendar(eventsSnapShot.data); // Passing the data
            }
          } 
          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),

// Methods

Widget _buildTableCalendar( List<Event> events ) {}

List<Event> _getEventsForDay( DateTime day, List<Event> event ) {}
```

Comment: Thank you @JesusCoronado for your response. I have tried both solutions but I am getting the same error.

Comment: if (eventsSnapShot.hasData) {
                setState(() => eventDoc = eventsSnapShot.data);
                return _buildTableCalendar(eventsSnapShot.data);
              }          List<Event> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day, [List<Event>? events]) {}

Comment: Please print your data from snapshot before the return _buildTableCalendar(eventsSnapShot.data);, maybe the data list is not being transformed in the correct way, and then let me know the result

Comment: Here is the output from this line of code: print('eventDoc: ' + eventsSnapShot.data.toString());     OUTPUT:  eventDoc: null,    It loops through again...OUTPUT: eventDoc: [Instance of 'Event', Instance of 'Event', Instance of 'Event']

Comment: If I evaluate eventsSnapshot.data I see data.

Comment: Thank you for let me know the result, i think you could add other validation inside your StreamBuilder, i will edit the response code.